# LibGDX what resolution should I draw my Images (PoT or can i choose?)

Tags: android, image, libgdx, desktop-application, resolution

What are the pixel dimentions usualy used for games?
My game would be on Android and Desktop. I dont want pixelart images. I whant smooth images (like Fruit Ninja) at first for 2D games but 3D would nice to be known.

- Should I daw my images in PoT?
- Draw Images in low / mid / high resolution and the user define the quality?
- What dimentions are usual for the low / mid / high res. images?
- What res. would a big company like CD Project RED or Ubisoft use?

Comment: What does "daw my images in PoT" mean?

Comment: draw my images in resolutions like 16, 32, 64, 128...

Comment: PoT means power of two. So the width and height size of an image are the power of two.

Answer (score 2):

You should draw your images in whatever size makes sense for you. Also, you should [pack](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer) multiple images into a single texture which should be power of two sized. Which size per image you use depends on your needs but it should typically not exceed the size (in pixels) of the target screen it is actually displayed on. You could use [multiple files depending on resolution](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backends-gwt/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/gwt/emu/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/loaders/resolvers/ResolutionFileResolver.java). But overall it sounds like you're trying to solve an non-existing problem.

Comment: Just whanted to know to do all correct. Thanks for the awser!